# Can a private static member be used as a default argument to a member function of its class?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Which one of the compilers is right ?

```
class A
{
public:
   template <typename T>
   void fun(void (*f)() = funPrivate<T>) {}
private:
   template <typename T>
   static void funPrivate() {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  A a;
  a.fun<int>();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiles fine on: **gcc version 4.8.5 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)**

Results in a error on: **clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)**

```
    a.cpp:5:27: error: 'funPrivate' is a private member of 'A'
   void fun(void (*f)() = funPrivate<T>) {}
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    a.cpp:14:3: note: in instantiation of default function argument expression for 'fun<int>' required here
      a.fun<int>();
      ^
    a.cpp:8:16: note: declared private here
       static void funPrivate() {}
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: This might be related to optimization. The line in question does nothing, so GCC may be optimizing it out. GCC doesn't always complain about errors in things it optimizes out. I would be curious what happened if you actually tried to use that function pointer.

Comment: @WilliamKappler [Nothing changed.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96df544565dac680)

Comment: Strangely, clang seems to accept it if you make `funPrivate` not a template.

Comment: @songyuanyao It's even weirder! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c27c76981d1a200e . I am not even going to attempt to say which of these, if either, is behaving correctly.

Comment: @WilliamKappler Code snippet in question is simplified but real world usage yields the same error

Comment: @user1650441 Yeah, I can see that: see my second comment. This actually seems to allow subversion of `private` as a whole, which I did not expect to be permitted. Perhaps clang is attempting to prevent that.

Comment: Without templates there is no error so I tend to think that clang behaviour is wrong or at least inconsistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§ 11

> 8  The names in a default argument (8.3.6) are bound at the point of declaration, and access is checked at that
>   point rather than at any points of use of the default argument. Access checking for default arguments in
>   function templates and in member functions of class templates is performed as described in 14.7.1.

§ 14.7.1

> 12 If a function template `f` is called in a way that requires a default argument to be used, the dependent names
>     are looked up, the semantics constraints are checked, and the instantiation of any template used in the default
>    argument is done as if the default argument had been an initializer used in a function template specialization
>   with the same scope, the same template parameters and the same access as that of the function template `f`
>   used at that point. This analysis is called *default argument instantiation*. The instantiated default argument
>   is then used as the argument of `f`.

So, according to this, I would guess that gcc's interpretation is right.  `fun` has access to private members, so its default arguments should be considered in that same access. But I am reading between the lines that 14.7.1(12) applies to member templates, and not just function templates.  Also I may be misunderstanding that 14.7.1(12) means.

Comment: If 14.7.1(12) by template functions implies also template method this would be a definitive answer

Answer (score 0):

I have tested code in msvc13. This code works:

```
class A
{
  template <typename T>
  static void funPrivate() {}
public:
  template <typename T>
  void fun(void (*f)() = funPrivate<T>) {}
};
```