# The private member function's action scope

Tags: c++, clion

## The Issue：

Class declaration is as below：

```
class Select {
public:
    template<typename Iterator>
    static Iterator function(Iterator , Iterator , bool (*judgeFunction)(Iterator A, Iterator B) = priFunction);

private:
    template<typename Iterator>
    inline static bool priFunction(Iterator , Iterator);
```

And my test file is as below:

```
template <typename T>
void showFunction(std::vector<T> &A){
    Select S;
    std::cout<<*S.function(A.begin(),A.end())<<std::endl;
}
```

CLion remarked an error for the test file：

```
In template: 'priFunction' is a private member of 'Select'
```

I used the following sentence compiled my CppFile：

```
g++ -o ExeFile CppFile.cpp -I "../../../Include/"
```

And its ExeFile ran successfully.

## My Question

1. Can the member function in private or protected scope of a class be declared as a default parameter in the class' public functions' parameter list?
2. If there's no error in fact，How could I hide the error reminder of CLion?(unecessary)

My Clion version is 2022.1.3.

Comment: What version of CLion are you using? With the latest (2022.2) I don't get any message similar to yours.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I forgot to submit my test file(where CLion remarded the error). And I just edited it, please review the problem description。

Comment: And my Clion version is 2022.1.3

Comment: The same problem with Clang. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YW1oYGqja)

Comment: For a proper [mre] see [this gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/pileon/b6b8b041c2755a076569ce51a6799247). It builds cleanly (only an unused parameter warning) with GCC but doesn't run. It does show the "error" in CLion.

Comment: @JiangZiyang It is a clang error not gcc's error. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73218934/12002570) below.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually it's just a simple function select the min element, which is my practice of Algorithms learning. After defining the function and compile it, it runs.

Comment: This seems to be an ancient issue with gcc/clang. Possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617717/can-a-private-static-member-be-used-as-a-default-argument-to-a-member-function-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is well-formed as we're allowed to use `priFunction` as a default argument the way you did in the above example.

This seems to be a **clang bug**. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aaoEE4Tnd). As you can see in the above link, clang also give the error:

```
<source>:6:100: error: 'priFunction' is a private member of 'Select'
    static Iterator function(Iterator , Iterator , bool (*judgeFunction)(Iterator A, Iterator B) = priFunction);
                                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:17: note: in instantiation of default function argument expression for 'function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int>>>' required here
    std::cout<<*S.function(A.begin(),A.end())<<std::endl;
                ^
<source>:21:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'showFunction<int>' requested here
 showFunction(v);
 ^
<source>:10:24: note: declared private here
    inline static bool priFunction(Iterator , Iterator){return true;}
```

---

GCC and MSVC correctly compiles the program without any problem. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T9KsndWjG)